# Prop spreading in react navigation <drawerItems>

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I building a react native app in typescript. I am using a drawerItems component from react navigation.

```
<DrawerItems
  {...this.props}
  items={items}
  itemStyle={styles.drawerItem}
  labelStyle={material.body1}
  activeBackgroundColor="transparent"
/>
```

I have set my lint on very strict for learning purposes. And now i have the following error message:

> Prop spreading is forbiddeneslint(react/jsx-props-no-spreading)

I have tried to pass the props seperated but it needs other props that i do not know where to get from. Can anyone show me how to rewrite this without prop spreading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I debugged the props and put all the childs in the  seperately.
The finished code looks like this:

```
            <DrawerNavigatorItems
              items={items}
              itemStyle={styles.drawerItem}
              labelStyle={material.body1Object}
              activeBackgroundColor="transparent"
              drawerPosition="left"
              renderIcon={renderIcon}
              getLabel={getLabel}
              onItemPress={onItemPress}
            />
```

Please note that i also updated my packages in the meantime so the original childs of ...props could have been different

Comment: So instead of improving your code you have made it less readable and robust to future update. In the absence of a better solution, maybe the best solution in this case is to disable the rule for this line: `/* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading */`

Comment: Well as stated in the original question i have set it to strict because of learning purposes. I assumed the linter rules were the truth because i was still a beginner in react-native. Readability and robustness were not the goal of this project, it was to understand react-native. And by figuring out this prop spreading question i learned a lot about it. The linter rule helped me here.